# How do I create a spot light effect in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, vignetting

Having an effect of round spot light on the picture, so in the middle it's lighter and close to corners darker —  what is the name of this effect in photography?

What is the technique for this in Lightroom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Vignetting** - In the Develop module if you expand the *Effects* section, you will see what they call the Post-Crop Vignetting tool. Adjust the sliders as you see fit.

Comment: Exacty what I want! Thx

Comment: Also, please do us all a favour and *not* use the white-vignette end of the slider. :-)